# Difference in UI which will need to be tailored for different environments

Tags: android

I am a beginner to Android.
I quote from from ***Version 6.3*** of the book ***The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development*** by ***Mark L. Murphy***. He puts forward,

Sometimes, your UI will work across all sorts of devices: ***phones, tablets, televisions,*** etc. Sometimes, your UI will need to be tailored for different environments. 
Sometimes, supporting larger screens means you will want to ***snap together*** parts of your smaller-screen UI.

```
For example, Gmail on a tablet will show your list of labels, the list of
conversations in a selected label, and the list of messages in a selected 
conversation, all in one activity. However, Gmail on a phone cannot do 
that, as there is not enough screen space, so it shows each of those 
(labels, conversations, messages) in separate activities.
```

Now, considering how the ***Gmail UI*** renders on,

***Samsung Galaxy A7***

[image]

***Samsung Galaxy Tab3***

[image]

I hardly find any difference b/w the 2 images. So, what exactly is he trying to suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what exactly is he trying to suggest?

That passage is out of date, reflecting an older version of Gmail. It also was focused on landscape and 10" tablets.

The chapter on large-screen strategies shows screenshots of the Gmail UI that I was referring to, such as the tablet activity, presently showing two out of three fragments (labels and conversations shown, messages being the third):

[image: Original Gmail Android App, 10" Tablet, Landscape]

This is the same as the phone UI (again, from that older edition of Gmail), except that on a phone, only one of those fragments would be shown at a time, owing to the smaller screen size.

Comment: That's amazing. You have a very high reputation. I agree that the tablet from I had taken the screenshot is around 7'' inches. One more thing if the passage is out of date, do I continue with the book or not.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: "One more thing if the passage is out of date, do I continue with the book or not" -- programming books in rapidly evolving areas frequently are out of date, at least in various aspects. If you are only interested in books that are completely up to date, you will need to focus on older technologies, ones that have not changed since the last books discussing them are published. In this case, it would help if you were an active subscriber (I have no record of a purchase from you), as I will make sure to get these Gmail references cleaned up in Version 6.7.

Comment: I searched this book on online stores. Unfortunately, all these e-commerce websites Amazon, Flipkart, Snapdeal have got very very older versions. Now, if I get it from outside, It would be too expense for me considering India economic factors & currency. Education itself is too expensive these days.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: "I searched this book on online stores" -- it is not sold in online stores, other than [my own](https://commonsware.com/Android). If you do not want to pay for books, "considering India economic factors & currency", only use books that are released legitimately for free, such as [older editions of my book](https://commonsware.com/Android/4-2-free), rather than pirating them.

Comment: @CommonWare: For your information, I don't pirate books. I purchase them. See also, http://www.flipkart.com/busy-coder-s-guide-advanced-android-development-english-2nd/p/itmdvzuvmfxhpznz

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: That is not Version 6.3, which is what you cited in your question. That is also a different book, and in print form. And, since I don't have you on record as buying the book from me, wherever you got it from, it was pirated, as I am the sole source of Version 6.3, at least for another ~18 months or so, when it should be added to the Creative Commons-licensed roster. If you think you paid for it, whoever you bought Version 6.3 from pirated it, and you should reconsider purchasing from that vendor.

Comment: I accessed the sample material from here https://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt-6p3.pdf  . Page 6. How can then it be pirated. It really rude of you to put such a blame on me.

Comment: @ShirgillAnsari: Ah! That's perfectly legitimate. I'll have to ensure that I update that excerpt as well, as that's getting a bit old (not to mention for the Gmail references you cited). My sincere apologies, as I had forgotten that the free excerpt would cover this portion of the book (it used to be another chapter). "It really rude of you to put such a blame on me" -- I agree completely. Again, I apologize for my behavior.